# Best way to save PHP output to a static file?

Tags: php, xml, curl, rss, podcast

I have a PHP page that outputs XML. But for efficiency reasons, it's probably best to serve an XML page. Right?

The XML is podcast RSS data. http://kansaspublicradio.org/widgets/podcasts/retro-cocktail-hour.php and there's one more just like it for a different show. The PHP code gathers the data from our CMS (drupal) and puts it in the itunes specific XML tags. I found this to be a better solution than any available drupal module.

But it's a little unconventional to serve XML with a PHP file. And that PHP code will be executed anytime anyone, or any*thing* i.e. itunes or feedburner, makes a request for the RSS data. The PHP code just queries the database then loops through the results to write the XML tags, but there's still an inherent memory and sql performance hit every time.

So I need to serve a static XML file. How can I save the output of the PHP to a file??

I imagine I'll create another PHP script, like makepodcast.php, that runs the original PHP page but prints it's output to an XML page. Then I can make a cron job that does this once a week (the show is recorded weekly).

But what I'm lost on is just how exactly do I save the output of a PHP and write it to another file??

Comment: [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php)?

Comment: I wouldn't consider php serving XML "unconventional". XML is pretty similar to HTML (or even XHTML *is* XML) and there is nothing unconventional about serving HTML. If all your feed is doing is pulling from db and echo'ing results, that is pretty much the most basic thing that PHP does.

Comment: You're right about that, in general. I guess I should have been a little more clear. The unconvential part is that, when someone or something click the link for the RSS data, they'll get a PHP page and not an XML page. They'll be expecting an XML page. This is specific to podcasting. I want to submit this to iTunes soon and it could confuse the damn thing. iTunes is very picky....

Comment: Are you using an XML Library ?

Comment: If you sent an XML header and used mod_rewrite to rewrite `feed.xml` to `feed.php` there would be no way to tell that the file wasn't an xml file on disk. I'm not arguing that the file shouldn't be cached. If the underlying feed data was updated infrequently writing to a file would be a good thing. Just saying that this is pretty common and easy for php to handle and you might be adding extra complexity that is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to organise your XML's Build : per period, per signal, per event ?
Once it is done, you can write something like :

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/xml");

    define ('XML_FILE_PATH', 'CUSTOMIZE/YOUR/XML/FILE/PATH');

    if ($_MUST_BUILD_XML) {
        // put here your old PHP code that it will build your XML file 
        // i guess that it is something like $xml = '<xml>
        //                                              <videogame>
        //                                                  <ps4>The Best One :) </ps4>
        //                                              </videogame>'
        buildXmlFile('built_file.xml', $xml);
        print $xml;
    }
    else {
        print readXmlFile('built_file.xml'); 
    }

    /**
      * @return string : built XML data
      * @param string  : XML file path and name
      * @throws Exception
      */
    function buildXmlFile($data_s, $file_name_s) {
        $fp = fopen ("XML_FILE_PATH/" . $file_name_s , "w");
        if(!$fp) { 
            /*TODO Error*/ throw new Exception('...');
        }

        fputs($f, $data_s);
        fclose ($f);
    }

    /**
      * @param string  : XML file path and name
      * @return string : built XML data
      * @throws Exception
      */
    function readXmlFile($file_name_s) {
        $fp = fopen ("XML_FILE_PATH/" . $file_name_s , "r");
        if(!$fp) { 
            /*TODO Error*/ throw new Exception('...');
        }

        $contents = fread($fp, filesize("XML_FILE_PATH/" . $file_name_s);
        fclose ($f);
        return ($contents);
    }
```

Hope that helpls :)

Comment: thanks! I'm going to try and implement this today. Having some efficiency issues after changing to another server, old server must have had some hidden php caching or something

Answer (score 0):

> But it's a little unconventional to serve XML with a PHP file.

That's actually very conventional.

> And that PHP code will be executed anytime anyone, or anything i.e. itunes or feedburner, makes a request for the RSS data.

Consider caching the output - PHP's [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.apc.php) can be very handy for this, or you could use `file_get_contents` / `file_put_contents` to make your own very simple file-based cache.

Comment: You're right about that, in general. I guess I should have been a little more clear. The unconventional part is that, when someone or something click the link for the RSS data, they'll get a PHP page and not an XML page. They may be expecting an XML page. This is specific to podcasting. I want to submit this to iTunes soon and it could confuse the damn thing. iTunes is very picky...

Comment: @DanMantyla You can serve XML with PHP, you just have to set the right `Content-Type` headers. https://wordpress.org/news/feed/ is an example - that's all generated on-the-fly by PHP.